# Upgrading visual studio solution to 9.2 - System.Interactive.Async and providers - need to supply runtime policy?

Tags: upgrade

We're in the final stages of upgrading to Sitecore 9.2, using a fresh install and updating our existing Visual Studio solution using the new files. We're using everything from the bin folder from the fresh install, and all correct assembly versions of dlls.

For linq queries in view renderings, this gives us a green underline in our .cshtml file code:

"Assuming assembly reference 'System.Interactive.Async, version=3.0.1000.0, Culture=neutral' used by 'system.interactive.async.providers' matches identity 'system.interactive.async, version=3.0.3000.0, culture=neutral' of 'system.interactive.async', you may need to supply runtime policy."

[image]

If these are the correct version as given by Sitecore, how come Visual Studio has an issue with this for async linq queries please?

Any ideas welcome!

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: Check the assembly mappings inside `Views/web.config`. On more than one occasion have I found these to be out of sync with the ones found in the webroot.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the tip, but there are no assembly mappings in the views/web.config file. We do have the main web.config and a .csproj for the main project, but as far as im aware, they match. Sitecore support have said from initial enquiry that the xconnect libraries show similiar messages, so im unsure how best to proceed, to either solve the issue or just leave it. Will get a bit confusing for other developers using the repo source code.

Any further ideas welcome.

Thanks again,

Andy

Comment: Similar issue in version 9.3.